# Puppet: how do namespaces work with virtual resources, classes and definitions?

Tags: class, namespaces, virtual, puppet, definitions

New puppet user, trying to wrap my head around name spaces and so forth.

I am currently working on a module called `user`. It has a `unixuser` class and a `unixgroup` class in `unixuser.pp` and `unixgroup.pp`. I'll limit my question to the creation of users.

`init.pp` currently only contains:

```
class user {
  class {'user::unixuser': }
  class {'user::unixgroup': }

  # Create groups before creating users
  Class['user::unixgroup'] -> ['user::unixuser']
}
```

In `unixuser.pp` and `unixgroup.pp` I only want to define the virtual resources. The functions that do this should be in `functions.pp` for readability.

Question 1: Should `functions.pp` should only contain definitions or should the definitions sit inside a class? So in code, should `functions.pp` contain this:

```
class user::functions {
  define login ($uid, $gid) {
    user { $title:
      ensure  => present,
      uid     => $uid,
      gid     => $gid,
    }
  }
}
```

Or should `define login` not be in the user::functions class? If so, should the `define` line be `define user::login` or something else?

Going further, `unixuser.pp` will then contain something similar to the following (incomplete) stanza:

```
class user::unixuser {
  @something { 'admin':
    uid => 1000,
    gid => 1000,
  }
}
```

If all of this is finished then I will `realize` the users from `nodes.pp` with something like `realize User::Something['admin']`.

Question 2: How should the class `user::unixuser` be made aware of the `login` function? Is this done by having `class user::unixuser inherits user::functions` or should I have `include user::functions` or `class {'user::functions': }` or...?

Question 3: Based on question 2, what comes in the place of `@something` when the `user::unixuser` class plays nicely with `functions.pp`?

I tried to formulate the question to the best of my abilities but if it is still a bit chaotic I apologize. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off if a user is assigned to a group that group is auto required, so you shouldn't need the following,:

```
  # Create groups before creating users
  Class['user::unixgroup'] -> ['user::unixuser']
```

functions.pp looks fine try the following in init.pp:

```
class user {
  include user::functions
  include user::unixgroup
  include user::unixuser
}
```

and unixuser.pp:

```
class user::unixuser {
  login { 'admin':
    uid => 1000,
    gid => 1000,
  }
  ...
}
```